# what will happen if we merge multiple dataset without by defined

Tags: r, merge

how R will process a merge if by is not defined. FOr other language, it seems by is required, but in r, it seems like we can do `new_df<-merge(df1, df2)`. what kind of merge we will get from this? is it same as the one we define `by=`? Do we really need to find out which varable we need to use for by? or R is smart enough and will chose one for us?

Comment: By default `merge()` will use all columns with exactly the same name in both data frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the help (`?base::merge`): by default, `by = intersect(names(x), names(y))` - i.e. it will search for the column names common between two dataframes

Answer (score 0):

If you do `new_df <- merge(df1, df2)` it performs an inner join and the `by` by default is selected as common column column names in `df1` and `df2`.

You can find these specifications in `?merge`.

```
merge(x, y, by = intersect(names(x), names(y)),
      by.x = by, by.y = by, all = FALSE, all.x = all, all.y = all,
      sort = TRUE, suffixes = c(".x",".y"), no.dups = TRUE,
      incomparables = NULL, ...)
```

So by default `by` is `intersect(names(x), names(y))`. Also it is specified in `Details` section.

> By default the data frames are merged on the columns with names they both hav